# Combining -Indexes and +MultiViews in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've disabled browsing directories (-Indexes) and enabled the option for users to visit pages with and without .html file extension (+MultiViews). Like this:

```
Options -Indexes +MultiViews
```

It seems that that is causing a 403 'Forbidden' error with this url:

*example.com/blog*

when there is a directory called *blog* and a a file *blog.html*.

How do allow access to */blog.html* without the extension in the url, without allowing browsing access to */blog/*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off `directory slash` on your server  in order to access the file of the same name as directory.

Add the following line to your htaccess file

```
DirectorySlash off
```

See the official documentation of `DirectorySlash` on apache mod-dir page
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: When I understand it correctly, that option will make example.com/blog/ appear as example.com/blog - that is the behaviour it shows on my local server and on my hosting.

That's not what I need though and it didn't solve my issue: now both /blog and /blog/ are still both referring to the blog directory.